# Как разбить tkinter oval на 36 секторов?

Tags: python, gui, tkinter

Я создаю круг с помощью `create_oval()`. Как его разделить на сектора?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для рисования сектора, дуги или части круга, отсеченной хордой, есть функция `create_arc()`. Пример:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
canvas.pack()

d = 360 // 36

colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow']
color_index = 0
for a in range(0, 360, d):
    # start - угол начала дуги, extent - "длина" дуги в градусах
    # style - может быть PIESLICE (сектор), CHORD ("хорда") или ARC (дуга). По-умолчанию PIESLICE
    canvas.create_arc(5, 5, 295, 295, start=a, extent=d, style=ARC, outline=colors[color_index])
    color_index = (color_index+1) % len(colors)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: а как замкнуть все ето в круг. Мне нужно просто потом повернуть етот круг.

Comment: @Oleg_Hudyma, рисуете 36 дуг - получается полный круг. Прикрепил скриншот работы программы.

Comment: спасибо большое)